# Oracle revoke privilege is not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-rac

I have setup Oracle 12c RAC with pluggable database and I am try to revoke privileges from DBA on DBA_XS_SESSION_ROLES table by using this command

```
REVOKE ALL ON SYS.DBA_XS_SESSION_ROLES FROM DBA;

Revoke succeeded.
```

it shows me revoke succeeded but it is not revoked yet. I am running this as **sys** user. How to troubleshoot the error ?

I use this command to verify privilege is revoked or not.

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'DBA_%'
```

Comment: How do you know it has not been revoked yet?

Comment: by looking at this output SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS

   WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'DBA_%'

Comment: You're revoking something from the built-in DBA role? And what output do you actually get from your query, specifically for DBA_XS_SESSION_ROLES FROM DBA?

Comment: GRANTEE              OWNER                TABLE_NAME                     GRANTOR              PRIVILEGE                      GRANTABLE  HIERARCHY  COMMON     TYPE
-------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------ -------------------- ------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------

DBA                  SYS                  DBA_XS_SESSION_ROLES           SYS                  SELECT                         NO         NO         YES        VIEW